# Can't get powershell to return where results from GCI using ACL

Tags: powershell, powershell-ise, powershell-4.0

I'm trying to get Powershell to list files in a directory that are older than a certain date and match a certain user. I've got the below script so far which gives me all the files older than a certain date and lists the directory and who owns them:

```
$date=get-date

$age=$date.AddDays(-30)

ls '\\server\share\folder' -File -Recurse | `
where {$_.lastwritetime -lt "$age"} | `
select-object $_.fullname,{(Get-ACL $_.FullName).Owner} | `
ft -AutoSize
```

However, when I try and use an additional where parameter to select only files owned by a certain user, I get no results at all, even though I know I should, based on the match I'm trying to obtain (as below):

```
$date=get-date

$age=$date.AddDays(-30)

ls '\\server\share\folder' -File -Recurse | `
where ({$_.lastwritetime -lt "$age"} -and {{(get-acl $_.FullName).owner} -eq "domain\user"}) | `
select-object $_.fullname,{(Get-ACL $_.FullName).Owner} | `
ft -AutoSize
```

Am I missing something? Can I not use the get-acl command in a where condition as I've tried to?

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This appears to work.

```
# Get the full list of files
ls '\\server\share\folder' -File -Recurse |
# Limit to files with the right age and owner
where {($_.lastwritetime -lt "$age") -and ((get-acl $_.FullName).owner -eq "domain\user")} |
# Add an Owner column to the object
ForEach-Object {$_ | Add-Member -type NoteProperty -name Owner -value (Get-ACL $_.FullName).Owner -PassThru} |
# Get just the filename and the owner
select-object fullname, owner |
# Format the output
ft -AutoSize
```

Also, a couple of tips.

- You had used the escape character at the end of each line. The pipe character will let you carry over to the next line, so there was no need for the escape.
- Also, `Where-Object` uses `{` and `}` to define the script block. Grouping conditions within the script block can be done using `(` and `)`.

Comment: You're a genius. Thank you so much. I didn't know about the add-member command.

Also, thanks for the other tips, I'll tidy up my other scripts now :)